# Changing variable values from object fields

Tags: java, android, object, boolean, field

The following is my code:

```
package com.collegeselector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;



public class CollegeList extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<CollegeItem> collegeLists=new ArrayList<CollegeItem>();
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comparator<CollegeItem> compare = new Comparator<CollegeItem>(){
    public int compare(CollegeItem a, CollegeItem b){
            return Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
    }
};


CollegeItem michigan = new CollegeItem(3.79,30,2020,"University of Michigan","Ann Arbor, Michigan",true,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
CollegeItem berkeley = new CollegeItem(3.84,30,2040,"University of California Berkeley","Berkeley, California",false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
CollegeItem stanford = new CollegeItem(3.96,33,2215,"Stanford University","Stanford, California",true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
CollegeItem mit = new CollegeItem(3.92,33,2206,"Massachusetts Institute of Technology","Cambridge,Massachusetts",true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
CollegeItem cit = new CollegeItem(3.95,34,2300,"California Institute of Technology","Pasadena,California",true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,false,false,false,true);
CollegeItem git = new CollegeItem(3.9,30,2010,"Georgia Institute of Technology","Atlanta,Georgia",true,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true);
CollegeItem uiuc = new CollegeItem(3.4,28,1975,"University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign","Champaign,Illinois",true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true);
CollegeItem carnegie = new CollegeItem(3.69,31,2100,"Carnegie Mellon University","Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false,true,false,true,false);
CollegeItem cornell = new CollegeItem(3.87,31,2150,"Cornell Univeristy","Ithaca, New York",false,true,false,true,true,true,true,false,true,false,true,true);
CollegeItem princeton = new CollegeItem(3.87,33,2260,"Princeton University","Princeton, New Jersey",true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
CollegeItem purdue = new CollegeItem(3.7,27,1749,"Purdue University","West Lafayette, Indiana",true,true,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,true,false,true);
CollegeItem utaustin = new CollegeItem(3.72,28,1854,"University of Texas at Austin","Austin, Texas",true,false,false,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true);
CollegeItem northwestern = new CollegeItem(3.8,32,2155,"Northwestern University","Evanston, Illinois",false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,false);
CollegeItem wisconsin = new CollegeItem(3.84,28,1905,"University of Wisconsin-Madison","Madison, Wisconsin",false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false);
CollegeItem calpoly = new CollegeItem(3.87,28,1838,"California Polytechnic State University, San Luis Obispo","San Luis Obispo, California",false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
CollegeItem johnshopkins = new CollegeItem(3.72,32,2103,"Johns Hopkins University","Baltimore, Maryland",false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false);
CollegeItem pennstate = new CollegeItem(3.59,27,1778,"Pennsylvania State University-University Park","University Park, Pennsylvania",false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,true,false);
CollegeItem rice = new CollegeItem(3.87,32,2155,"Rice University","Houston, Texas",false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
CollegeItem texasam = new CollegeItem(3.6,27,1755,"Texas A&M University","College Station, Texas",false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false);
CollegeItem vtech = new CollegeItem(3.77,28,1823,"Virginia Tech","Blacksburg, Virginia",false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,true,false,false);







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    collegeLists.add(michigan);collegeLists.add(purdue);
    collegeLists.add(berkeley);collegeLists.add(utaustin);
    collegeLists.add(stanford);collegeLists.add(northwestern);
    collegeLists.add(mit);collegeLists.add(wisconsin);
    collegeLists.add(cit);collegeLists.add(calpoly);
    collegeLists.add(git);collegeLists.add(johnshopkins);
    collegeLists.add(uiuc);collegeLists.add(pennstate);
    collegeLists.add(carnegie);collegeLists.add(rice);
    collegeLists.add(cornell);collegeLists.add(texasam);
    collegeLists.add(princeton);collegeLists.add(vtech);



    Collections.sort(collegeLists, compare);

    for(CollegeItem collegeList : collegeLists){
        nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));



}
private class CollegeItem {
private double gpa;
private int act;
private int sat;
private String name;
private String location;
private double score;
private boolean match;
private double scoreDistance;

private boolean uaero, uagri, ubio, uchem, ucivil, ucomp, uelec, uphys, uenvi, uindus, umate, umech;

public CollegeItem(double gpa, int act, int sat, String name, String location, boolean uaero, boolean uagri, boolean ubio, boolean uchem,
                    boolean ucivil, boolean ucomp, boolean uelec, boolean uphys, boolean uenvi, boolean uindus, boolean umate, boolean umech){
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.act = act;
    this.sat = sat;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.uaero = uaero;
    this.uagri = uagri;
    this.ubio = ubio;
    this.uchem = uchem;
    this.ucivil = ucivil;
    this.ucomp = ucomp;
    this.uelec = uelec;
    this.uphys = uphys;
    this.uenvi = uenvi;
    this.uindus = uindus;
    this.umate = umate;
    this.umech = umech;

    if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    if(uaero&&ListOfMajors.aerospace)
        match = true;
    if(uagri&&ListOfMajors.agricultural)
        match = true;
    if(ubio&&ListOfMajors.biomed)
        match = true;
    if(uchem&&ListOfMajors.chem)
        match = true;
    if(ucivil&&ListOfMajors.civil)
        match = true;
    if(ucomp&&ListOfMajors.computer)
        match = true;
    if(uelec&&ListOfMajors.electrical)
        match = true;
    if(uphys&&ListOfMajors.physics)
        match = true;
    if(uenvi&&ListOfMajors.environment)
        match = true;
    if(uindus&&ListOfMajors.industrial)
        match = true;
    if(umate&&ListOfMajors.materials)
        match = true;
    if(umech&&ListOfMajors.mechanical)
        match = true;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public double getScoreDistance(){
    return this.scoreDistance;
}
```

CheckList Activity

```
public class ListOfMajors extends Activity {

    boolean[] mItemState;
    public static boolean aerospace, agricultural, biomed, chem, civil, computer, electrical, physics, environment, industrial, materials, mechanical;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.majorslist);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.majorslist);
        final String[] list={"Aerospace Engineering","Agricultural Engineering",
                "Biomedical Engineering","Chemical Engineering","Civil Engineering",
                "Computer Engineering","Electrical Engineering","Engineering Physics", 
                "Environmental Engineering","Industrial Engineering",
                "Materials Engineering","Mechanical Engineering"};
        mItemState = new boolean[list.length];
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfMajors.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
        mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Toggle the state
                mItemState[position] = !mItemState[position];
                if (mItemState[position])
                    switch(position){
                        case 0: aerospace = true;
                        case 1: agricultural = true;
                        case 2: biomed = true;
                        case 3: chem = true;
                        case 4: civil = true;
                        case 5: computer = true;
                        case 6: electrical = true;
                        case 7: physics = true;
                        case 8: environment = true;
                        case 9: industrial = true;
                        case 10: materials = true;
                        case 11: mechanical = true;                             
                    }

                else{
                    switch(position){
                        case 0: aerospace = false;
                        case 1: agricultural = false;
                        case 2: biomed = false;
                        case 3: chem = false;
                        case 4: civil = false;
                        case 5: computer = false;
                        case 6: electrical = false;
                        case 7: physics = false;
                        case 8: environment = false;
                        case 9: industrial = false;
                        case 10: materials = false;
                        case 11: mechanical = false;                                
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        mylist.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }

}
```

The variables such as uaero and uagri are boolean fields of objects. I have a quite a few objects in this class. The variables such as ListOfMajors.aerospace and ListOfMajors.agricultural are boolean values from another class which are set to true if a checkbox is clicked. All of these pairs of variables correspond with each other and would like the variable match set to true if both of the other variables are true. As of right now, the code doesn't seem to working as match doesn't appear to be changing to true. What should I do to get this to work?

Comment: you should go back and use Log.d() to see what is hapening with the checkboxes and step through with a debugger if you can to see what is happening

Comment: @JRowan I know that the checkboxes are working because I tested that out earlier, it's just that I'm not sure whether I'm comparing the two values correctly.

Comment: could you please post all the code to try it out?

Comment: Can you run your test through Eclipse debug to step through your logic? Are you using another IDE?  Cal we see the whole class?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I added the rest of the class.

Comment: This is unlikely to fix your problem, but I would set match using the following something like match = Uxxx && ListOfMajors.xxx || Uyyy && ListOfMajors.yyy || ....  Have you stepped your code through using debug mode?  Your code looks "right", so I would suspect that the variables passed in as parameters are somehow all false.

Comment: Would I need to add other classes

Comment: By the way, you never seem to use the variable match. Adding the ListActivity class and the class that calls this one may be useful.

Comment: I previously added a Log.d command in the if statements to display text if the statement was true. The message didn't show up.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I added the other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cases are probably not doing what you think .. since there is no break a case position 0 will set all of the variables to true (or false)

```
 switch(position){
                        case 0: aerospace = true; break;
                        case 1: agricultural = true;break;
                        case 2: biomed = true;break;
                        case 3: chem = true;break;
                        case 4: civil = true;break;
                        case 5: computer = true;break;
                        case 6: electrical = true;break;
                        case 7: physics = true;break;
                        case 8: environment = true;break;
                        case 9: industrial = true;break;
                        case 10: materials = true;break;
                        case 11: mechanical = true;   break;                          
                    }
```